# Displaying the ASCII-Code of a char in assembly

Tags: assembly, ascii, x86-16, masm, dosbox

I'm kinda new to assembly and I want to know how to get a char ASCII code and print out that ASCII code. I'm using MASM (Dosbox).

```
MOV AX, 'A'  ; -> I want to print out the ASCII code of 'A'
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You mean you want to print `65`? Just print `AX` as a number. Divide by 10, print the two digits.

Comment: @Jester like this?: MOV AX, 'A'
  MOV BX, 10
  DIV BL
  MOV AH, 2
  INT 21h

Comment: You will need to handle both digits and have to convert back to text (add `'0'`).

Comment: After DIV: ADD AH, 48 ADD AL, 48?

Comment: Yes but you will have to print them separately.

Comment: I got this output: ##

Comment: Read about how to solve this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments

> `MOV AX, 'A'` `MOV BX, 10` `DIV BL` `MOV AH, 2` `INT 21h`

This byte-sized division will leave a quotient in `AL` and a remainder in `AH`.
But the DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h expects its input in the `DL` register.

> After DIV: `ADD AH, 48` `ADD AL, 48`

Fine to convert, but you can do it in one go with `ADD AX, 3030h`

> I got this output: ##

Try next code:

```
mov ax, 'A'
mov bl, 10
div bl
add ax, 3030h
mov dx, ax      ; Moving tens "6" to DL for printing and preserving the units in DH
mov ah, 02h     ; DOS.PrintCharacter
int 21h
mov dl, dh      ; units "5"
mov ah, 02h     ; DOS.PrintCharacter
int 21h
```

[Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) has a detailed explanation about how to deal with even bigger numbers.

Comment: First `mov ah, 02h` clobbers `ah` before loading it into `dl`. Better: `mov dx, ax` and `mov dl, dh`

Comment: I tried the code, but got this output: ##65. The question is why am i getting this: ##

Comment: @daniel19 Those ## must come from *something earlier on* in your program. The code snippet that I posted can not output by itself those redundant characters. Why don't you edit the question and include the whole program source?